# Error using abstract type in C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I have some weird problems when implementing an intrusive container in C++.
Given the following simplified code:

```
struct IFace {
  virtual int foo() const = 0;
};

struct Impl : public IFace {
  int foo() const { return 111; }
};

template <typename T> struct IntrusiveHook {
  T item;
  IntrusiveHook<T>* next;
};

template <typename T> struct IntrusiveList {
  IntrusiveList() : head(0), tail(0) {}

  template <typename U>
  void add(IntrusiveHook<U>& addItem) {
    if (0 == head) {
      head = reinterpret_cast<IntrusiveHook<T>*>(&addItem);
      tail = head;
    }
    else {
      tail->next = reinterpret_cast<IntrusiveHook<T>*>(&addItem);
      tail = tail->next;
    }
  }
  IntrusiveHook<T>* head;
  IntrusiveHook<T>* tail;
};

void testList() {
  IntrusiveHook<Impl> impl;
  IntrusiveList<IFace> list;

  list.add(impl);
  // list.head->item.foo();
}
```

I get the following error message - for the "add"-call (when commenting out the line `list.head->item.foo()` as above):

```
error C2259: 'IFace' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'int IFace::foo(void) const' : is abstract
testwas.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'IFace::foo'
testwas.cpp(25) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IntrusiveHook<T>' being compiled
with
[
  T=IFace
]
testwas.cpp(41) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void IntrusiveList<T>::add<Impl>(IntrusiveHook<Impl> &)' being compiled
with
[
  T=IFace
]
```

When commenting in the line `list.head->item.foo()` I get a different compile error, the previous one has been left out (which is a strange behavior and occurs both on VC++ and gcc compilers)

The problematic call seems to be `tail->next = ...` or especially the operator `->` on the abstract type used here.

So:
how to fix this problem?

- add a default implementation fo `foo` in the `IFace` - which is not what I desire, but it fixes the problem
- kind of hacky solution: rewrite the to `tail->next` as

  `reinterpret_cast<IntrusiveHook<U>*>(tail)->next = &addItem;`

  `tail = reinterpret_cast<IntrusiveHook<T>*>(reinterpret_cast<IntrusiveHook<U>*>(tail)->next);` - but it does not seem to work with VC++(2010), but with gcc
- ... or performing some other ugly casts

But *WHY* is this a problem in the first place? Normally it should not be a problem to access a pointer type with operator "->".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Edit:

Just for convenience I would have liked to have the IntrusiveHook already contain the item as an instance. This is also the trick with intrusive - when I got that right - to just add the pointer-functionality to the item without changing the item itself. "new" is not an option, as the code should run in an embedded environment without `new`.

Also of course I would like to use a list with the abstract items, because the using class would not know of the implementation classes.

Comment: IntrusiveList<Impl> list;
list.add(impl);

Comment: or `IntrusiveList<IFace*> list; list.add(new Impl());` just as the error says: you cannot instantiate objects of an abstract class. Your IntrusiveList cannot work with `IFace` because this is not a complete type, but it could work with `IFace*` (because to declare a pointer you do not need to know the complete type)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, the problem is the cast to `IntrusiveHook<T>*` in `IntrusiveList::add`. You are casting `addItem` to `IntrusiveHook<IFace>`. `IntrusiveHook<IFace>` has the member `item` of the type `IFace`. But `IFace` is abstract, so you cannot declare a variable with that type -- you have to use a pointer or a reference.

So you have to

- change `IntrusiveHook::item` from type `T` to `T*`,
- add a constructor `IntrusiveHook(T* item) : item(item) {}`,
- change the declaration of `impl` in `testList()` to `IntrusiveHook<Impl>  impl(new Impl)`
- and finally change `list.head->item.foo()` to `list.head->item->foo()`.

(See [this code on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/5rtm).)

You could also use `IntrusiveList<IFace*>` or `IntrusiveList<Impl>` instead of `IntrusiveList<IFace>` if you don't want to change `IntrusiveHook`.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use "new" - this would have been much easier then. Also there is no need for creating an intrusive type when using dynamic memory.

Comment: @michael_s I'm not familiar with the concept of intrusive types. Yet it is simply not possible to declare a variable with an abstract type in C++. You have to use either pointers or references, or a non-abstract class.